# What's the minimum amount of transistors I need to operate a stepper motor?

Tags: transistors, motor, stepper-motor, coil

I would like to know the minimum amount of transistors to operate a stepper motor.
Could I pilote it with one transistor or I need one transistor for every coil?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: the minimum number N of transistors I should connect to ports to drive the stepper motor. 
For example, if I have 4 coils, I think I should have 4 bjt to drive my motor [image: http://electronic-projects.50webs.com/image/1.jpg].

My question is actually: does exist a stepper motor with 4 coils that could I drive with only one of these bjt like this? [image: http://playwithrobots.com/images/old/one%20transistor%20motor.jpg]

(I know this last circuit is for dc motor but somebody told me I could drive a stepper motor with this same circuit.... is that true?)

Comment: Pilote? What’s that?

Comment: Huh? What's "pilote"?

Comment: Including in your microcontroller?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "to drive/operate".

Comment: There is a schematic tool on the editor toolbar. Add in a schematic of your one transistor circuit you are thinking of. (There is no motor symbol so use the inductor or lamp symbol for the motor coils.)

Comment: Use the image button to add the images inline in your post so we don't have to follow links to understand your question.

Comment: Why do you need to save transistors? They should be pretty cheap. And small.

Comment: 1K base resistor on a 2N3055, that like putting roller-blade wheels on a Mustang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcAM31.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A typical stepper motor with two coils.*

It should be obvious that to generate a rotational sequence that one transistor is not enough to switch even a two-coil stepper motor.

DC motors and stepper motors are quite different. DC motors run continuously and are not capable of stepping.

The minimum number of switches required is shown in your first diagram: four.

Comment: Actually, there are fixed-direction stepping motors that only require one switch, commonly found in (and largely limited to) clocks.

Comment: but those motors only have a single coil.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the minimum amount of transistors I need to pilote a stepper motor?

I don't know what you mean by "pilote", but if you are asking what the minimum number of transistors are to operate a stepper motor, then the answer is 0.

To make a stepper motor rotate, at a minimum you need to switch ends of some coils between open, and connected to a power supply.  This does not require transistors.  You could, for example, manually make the sequence of connections, use relays, or other mechanical means.

A interesting demonstration would be to set up brushes on a shaft to go thru one step sequence.  Each rotation of that control shaft would cause one step in the stepper motor.  It would be kindof like a "electrical gearbox".  You could add a little disclamer to the bottom: *"No transistors were abused in the making of this demonstration"*.

Answer (score 2):

For an ordinary stepper motor, you do indeed need four transistors or comparable switches for a unipolar motor, and 8 for a bipolar one.

However, there are some variations.  3-wire steppers exist, mostly as the low-torque open-loop mode of brushless DC motors.

There is also a way of wiring a high impedance stepper-like motor with a phase shift capacitor to be operated from a single-phase AC supply.  In theory that could be generated with a single transistor.

And then there are special single-coil stepper motors as found in battery powered clocks.  These are low torque and **are not electrically reversible(!)**.  Regardless of the direction of the current applied, they always step in the same direction determined by the physical topology of magnetically permeable materials forming the flux path.  However, as a result **you need only a single transistor** or similar switch to step them.  You could almost argue that this is a variation on a solenoid pushing a ratchet, only it is the magnetic design rather than a mechanical ratchet pawl which makes it work.